# Manage ADLSGen2 ACLs with Shared Key Access Disabled?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

On ADLS Gen2 (Azure Blob Storage with HNS enabled), we assign access via Access Control Lists (ACL), see [ADLS Gen2 access control models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control-model).
However, if we disable "Storage account key access", we loose the ability to edit the ACLs with the error:

> "Failed to update ACL for path (...). Error: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission"

This is quite counter-intuitive, given that Microsoft [discourages shared (account) keys, and encourages ACL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/security-recommendations).

In the Azure portal, one can toggle between using Authentication method: *Azure AD User Account* or *Access key* when browsing data. (The latter is not possible when we disable access keys.)
But in ACL management, it is not possible to choose a similar Authentication Method, and I suspect that they only support access keys.

Is this a feature or a bug? How do we mange ACL with shared keys diasabled?

Comment: Did you figure this out @Martin? Just came across the same issue today. Can't figure out which IAM permission is required, their docs just state blob owner which is clearly not the case.

Comment: @JamesCrowley Unfortunately no. A workaround is to enable access keys, edit the ACL's then disable access keys again :-(

Comment: turns out (for us at least), it was the 'Storage Blob Data Owner' that was missing - you need specifically that, other roles will not do it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specifically need the 'Storage Blob Data Owner' role assigned and scoped so it applies to the relevant container. The 'Owner' role on it's own, for instance, does not work.

Comment: You are right, this works for me! (It took a few minutes before it worked.)
The role description indeed reads:
[Storage Blob Data Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-owner) "Provides full access to Azure Storage blob containers and data, including assigning POSIX access control."